# Shell Script ( Send the file from date wise directory ) - Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What I have in the system :

There is archive directory ( date wise ) where one file is getting saved after its processing every day.

example(s) are : 
The directory name would be: 20170707 > temp_process.txt
The directory name would be: 20170708 > temp_process.txt

Requirement is:
I would like to write a shell script which sends this file every day to the specific email every day only once.

Here, it should fetch the file from date wise directory ( i.e No static directory ).

Please help me for the same.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: I lost my access to the server hence I have not provided the script which I was written, Now I got it back. #!/bin/sh
customer='mycustomer'
jobname='SendSource'
customerEmailAddress='riddhi@xyz.com'

fileTimestamp=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
dataDir=${MY_HOME}/../data/archive/${fileTimestamp}
filename='*Source*.txt'

cd $dataDir
if [ -e ${dataDir}/${filename} ]
then
mail -s " Source file" -a "$filename" $customerEmailAddress
fi

Comment: But seems it is too slow, the file size is only 24 K and from last 20 minutes it is just running

Comment: Any help will be appreciated which help me for fast execution, I am trying to zip the file in script.

Answer (score 1):

Use find:

```
fil=$(find / -name "*.temp_process.txt" -ctime 0)
echo "test" | mailx -s test -a $fil someone@someserver.com
```

ctime 0 will only search for files created with in the last 24 hours

The results can then be used to action an email